# If statement to enable certain values based on button clicks C# and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create an if statement in my xaml.cs code that will allow me to enable certain values in check boxes, based on which button is pressed
For example: Button 1 enables values 1,2,3 and 4, button 2 enables 5,6,7 and 8

This is what I have so far

```
private void EnableAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(1 == true)
            {
                chk_1.IsChecked = true;
                chk_2.IsChecked = true;
                chk_3.IsChecked = true;
                chk_4.IsChecked = true;
            }

            if(1 == false)
            {
                chk_1.IsChecked = false;
                chk_2.IsChecked = false;
                chk_3.IsChecked = false;
                chk_4.IsChecked = false;
            }

            if(2 == true)
            {
                chk_5.IsChecked = true;
                chk_6.IsChecked = true;
                chk_7.IsChecked = true;
                chk_8.IsChecked = true;
            }

            if(2 == false)
            {
                chk_5.IsChecked = false;
                chk_6.IsChecked = false;
                chk_7.IsChecked = false;
                chk_8.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
```

This is linked the the XAML event below

```
        <Button Name="btnEnable_1" Content="Enable" Click="#make 1 true#"/>
        <Button Name="btnDisable_1" Content="Disable" Click="#make 1 false#"/>
```

The bits in Click= "" need to give the value of 1 as true and false respectively

I know what I want, but I don't know how to link them, and I'm sure there's an easier way to do it... If anyone can help, that would be amazing!

Comment: Just add two separate event handlers on your buttons.

Comment: I already had this, but it makes the code longer and less tidy, I was hoping an if statement could help me - not to mention, I have a button to disable everything, as well as the buttons to do only a certain number

Comment: @kyriacos_k - I was about to say the same thing!
It's not the best architecture, but you could just have your click handlers do the full switching. So btnEnable_1 click would set 1-4 checked and 5-8 unchecked, and btnDisable_1 would do the opposite?

Comment: @BenBarefield and If I just left it like that, could I run the enable everything, but pulling all the other enablers, or would I need an event to enable and disable everything?

Comment: It would surely be tidier than the code you have right now, which shouldn't even compile. But, you could use one event handler for both buttons and then determine which button fired it based on sender (cast sender to a Button), then use your if logic on that. Otherwise, you could use a toggle button.

Comment: @kyriacos_k I can't use a toggle button for a different reason in my code, but how would I do the cast sender, I've tried `Enable_1 button = sender as Enable_1;`  Enable_1 being the button that enables 1 through 4. It's currently in the class that enables the 4 check boxes

Comment: You cast using the Button type - check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event handler to each button

```
    <Button Name="btnEnable_1" Content="Enable" Click="myButton_Click" />
    <Button Name="btnDisable_1" Content="Disable" Click="myButton_Click" />
```

And in code behind:

```
    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var enabled = button.Name == "btnEnable_1";

        chk_1.IsChecked = enabled;
        chk_2.IsChecked = enabled;
        chk_3.IsChecked = enabled;
        chk_4.IsChecked = enabled;
        chk_5.IsChecked = !enabled;
        chk_6.IsChecked = !enabled;
        chk_7.IsChecked = !enabled;
        chk_8.IsChecked = !enabled;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. So this should only have 1-4, and it will enable the 4 check boxes. When I compile it, the disable button also works (without chk_5 onwards) Why is this? And if I add a `var disabled` in, the enable button disables and the disable button enables

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - but if you're looking to only enable four check boxes without disabling the rest, just use an if statement on button.Name and enable the desired check boxes accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I want it so Enable 1 just checks 1-4 and Enable 2 just checks 5-8, this goes in this pattern up to 64 values (16 Enable/Disable buttons). So it would be `if(button.Name == btnEnable_1) {chk_1.IsChecked = enabled; **etc** }` ? Or something else?

Comment: Exactly, but don't forget the double quotes around btnEnable_1 :)

Comment: What would I change `var enabled = button.Name == "btnEnable_1";` to if I'm using an if statement to fill the `btnEnable_1` part

Comment: You wouldn't use that in that case. Just say if (button.Name == "btnEnable_1") { ... } else if (button.Name == "btnEnable_2") { ... }